# Swift 3.0 Image Sets

Tags: ios, swift, image

How do I place three different size Images with same name(i.e. 640x1136 / 750x1334 / 1080x1920) in the Assets.xcassets folder?

In another words, I currently have three different size images stated above in the Assets.xcassets folder which I would like to use with UIImage object.
Do I need to name them all differently or name them the same?

```
//  Copyright © 2016 InspireInc. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var homeScreenBackgroundImage: UIImageView!

    var arrayOfHomeScreenBackgroundImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "HomeScreenBackgroundImage1.jpg")!]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        homeScreenBackgroundImage.image = arrayOfHomeScreenBackgroundImages[0]

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

How do I ensure that the right size image gets displayed on different devices?

Comment: For each image you add, Xcode automatically generates 2 more places for devices of different resolutions, you can put more images there

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have one option. You need to create UIImageView and create good constraints for example (top 0, bottom 0, leading 0, trailing 0) and then put your image to this UIImageView but with properly content mode. I prefer Aspect Fit in this case.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by " but with properly content mode"?